# What/Where is XP?

Tags: invisible-inc

Elsewhere on forums people say that when you retire an agency you get xp and with more xp you unlock more agents (and may be starting programs too?).

I can't see anywhere in the interface my current XP level. Where do I find it? Also is there a table or something that shows which XP level corresponds to which unlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can see the XP you have earned so far in the current run or your total while you are still playing, but XP is rewarded and your current total whenever a run completes - either because you win, fail or retire. If you do not complete a run (just leave it sitting there for some reason?) you will not earn the XP built up in that run so far - so if you're done with a run for any reason enter a mission and then retire to cash in the XP earned.

You will earn 100 XP for each level 1 mission completed, 150 per level 2 and 200 per level 3. If you've not seen them, the higher level missions will appear on later days as you progress.

---

You are correct that XP is used to unlock additional agents and starting programs - you can see these all greyed out on the starting setup screen (so you can see roughly how much you're missing).

Note that winning the game on Experienced difficulty (or higher) will provide a few special unlocks that will not be made available via XP. I'm being intentionally vague here because *spoilers* (for this reason I'd recommend just playing the game and seeing what unlocks as you go!).

Having performed a quick search I cannot find a decent list that provides a full list of what XP unlocks what, but for what it's worth, I had everything from before update 11 unlocked and if I start a new game and retire immediately I'm informed I have 3830XP, with 4430XP needed the next unlock.